# How to trigger email alert in salesforce using workflow rules when status changes from "New" to "Approved"

Tags: workflow, email-alert

I have a picklist named status which has different values to select. I want to trigger an email alert using workflow rules only when the status is changed from "New" to "Approved" and not otherwise.

How can I do that?
Full noob in salesforce.
Any help will be appreciated.

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Comment: The best place to get started with declarative automation is [Trailhead](https://trailhead.salesforce.com/en/content/learn/trails/automate_business_processes).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As a Workflow Rule, use the Formula Criteria option:

```
And(IsPickVal(PriorValue(Status, 'New')), IsPickVal(Status, 'Approved'))
```

Change Status in the above formula to whatever the API name is for the picklist field (custom fields send with "__c").